How can I make a message to Telegram topic (sub-group)?
I want to send a message to topic, but I have not found a way at GitLab issues and official doc.
from datetime import datetime

from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.custom import Dialog
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetForumTopicsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import PeerChannel, ForumTopic, InputPeerChannel
from telethon.tl.types.messages import ForumTopics


async def main(client: TelegramClient):
    async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():  # type: Dialog
        if not dialog.is_group:
            continue

        print(f"\n{dialog.id=} {dialog.name=}")
        if dialog.is_channel and dialog.entity.forum:
            input_peer_channel: InputPeerChannel = await client.get_input_entity(PeerChannel(dialog.entity.id))
            topics_request = GetForumTopicsRequest(
                channel=input_peer_channel, offset_date=datetime.now(), offset_id=-1, offset_topic=-1, limit=50
            )
            forum_topics: ForumTopics = await client(topics_request)
            for topic in forum_topics.topics:  # type: ForumTopic
                print(f"\t{topic.id=} {topic.title=}")
                # QUESTION: How can I send message to the topic?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    api_id = 123
    api_hash = '123...456'
    telegram_client = TelegramClient('user', api_id, api_hash)

    with telegram_client:
        telegram_client.loop.run_until_complete(main(telegram_client))

A way for sending a message to telegram's sub-group

You should be able to send a message with the reply_to=topic_id. Not entirely sure though.

Many thanks for @Lomami for a hint which solved my issue:
from datetime import datetime

from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.custom import Dialog
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetForumTopicsRequest, GetForumTopicsByIDRequest
from telethon.tl.types import PeerChannel, ForumTopic, InputPeerChannel, Message
from telethon.tl.types.messages import ForumTopics


async def main(client: TelegramClient):
    async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():  # type: Dialog
        if not dialog.is_group:
            continue

        print(f"\n{dialog.id=} {dialog.name=}")
        if dialog.is_channel and dialog.entity.forum:
            input_peer_channel: InputPeerChannel = await client.get_input_entity(PeerChannel(dialog.entity.id))
            topics_request = GetForumTopicsRequest(
                channel=input_peer_channel, offset_date=datetime.now(), offset_id=-1, offset_topic=-1, limit=50
            )
            forum_topics: ForumTopics = await client(topics_request)
            for topic in forum_topics.topics:  # type: ForumTopic
                print(f"\t{topic.id=} {topic.title=}")
                
                # This block was solved my issue
                entity: ForumTopics = await client(GetForumTopicsByIDRequest(channel=dialog.entity, topics=[topic.id]))
                channel: InputPeerChannel = await client.get_input_entity(PeerChannel(entity.chats[0].id))
                message: Message = await client.send_message(channel, "Hi there!", reply_to=topic.id)
                print(message.id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    api_id = 123
    api_hash = '123...456'
    telegram_client = TelegramClient('user', api_id, api_hash)

    with telegram_client:
        telegram_client.loop.run_until_complete(main(telegram_client))

